# How to display Json objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to display the data within a json file in javascript. my Json file is the following:

```
{
    "structure": [
        {
            "country": "Ecuador",
            "sport": "soccer",
            "id": "545",
            "age": "23",
            "gender": "male"
        },
        {
            "country": "USA",
            "sport": "Golf",
            "age": "22",
            "id": "2",
            "gender": "female"
        },
        {
            "gender": "male",
            "id": "3",
            "sport": "Basketball",
            "age": "21",
            "country": "Argentina"
        },
        {
            "gender": "female",
            "sport": "Tennis",
            "id": "4",
            "age": "20",
            "country": "Colombia"
        },
        {
            "country": "Venezuela",
            "gender": "male",
            "age": "19",
            "sport": "Volleyball",
            "id": "5"
        }
    ]
}
```

and my javascript request the json file is the following:

```
var setup = function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   async = true;
    xhr.open("GET", "output.json", async);

    xhr.onload = function(){

        var finalResult = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(finalResult['structure']);
    };

 /*kick off the request*/
    xhr.send();
};
```

can anyone help me to display the actual data please?

Comment: How do you want to display it? In a table?

Comment: @cbuckley that would be perfect??

Comment: Have a look at https://www.dynatable.com/.

Comment: @cbuckley what about if I just want to display in in the console??

Comment: `console.log(this.responseText)`

Answer (score 0):

JSON is already text. Log it before you parse it: `console.log(this.responseText)`

Comment: Thank you everyone, but I figured out how do do it

Comment: Late to the game, but Chrome would be great too: `console.table(JSON.parse(this.responseText).structure)`